# GraphQL __InputValue and "using the GraphQL language"

Tags: graphql

The now-current edition of [the GraphQL specification](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/#sec-The-__InputValue-Type) says this about `defaultValue` on `__InputValue`:

> `defaultValue` may return a String encoding (using the GraphQL language) of the default value used by this input value in the condition a value is not provided at runtime. If this input value has no default value, returns null.

What is "the GraphQL language" in the parenthetical expression? Operationally, it seems as though this equates to "what JSON would use, except that enums are treated as strings, since JSON does not have enums", but I am uncertain if I am correctly interpreting what I am seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GraphQL specification defines how the language encodes supported values in 2.9, "Input Values": http://facebook.github.io/graphql/#Value (Referred to as `Value` in the rest of the spec)

This is the same syntax used to define default values in operation definitions. In that case, the language is used inside a GraphQL query document, but in the introspection case the snippet of language itself is returned as a string.

Comment: To be clear: `defaultValue` then gets interpreted based upon the `type` supplied in the `__InputValue`? So, `defaultValue="true"` means one thing for a `Boolean`, a different thing for a `String`, and yet a different thing for an enumerated list? I'm just trying to make sure that I understand how this would get used. Thanks!